# Flutter FirebaseAuth VerificationCompleted not working after 2023 in Phone Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase Phone Authentication in my mobile app to verify user phone numbers. However, I've noticed that the verificationCompleted method doesn't seem to be working properly after 2023.

Here's a code snippet for reference:

```
await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
  verificationCompleted: _onVerificationCompleted,
  verificationFailed: _onVerificationFailed,
  codeSent: _onCodeSent,
  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: _onCodeTimeout
);
```

I've checked the Firebase documentation and couldn't find any recent changes or updates that could be causing this issue. I've also reviewed my code and can't seem to find any errors.

Additionally, I've enabled the Play Integrity API to ensure the authenticity of my app's users.

Also use the latest dependices-
`implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0')`

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any suggestions for how I can resolve it.

I'm using Flutter for my mobile app development, and my Firebase dependencies are up to date.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

i just want to auto login when recive otp.

Comment: did you find some solution ?